# Correct way to log response body length in Play?

Tags: playframework

I'm looking for the best way to log response body length in a Play Filter.

Is there an approach better than the below?  I'm unclear if this approach will log the request in all cases. Is it possible that the Enumerator will not be fully consumed if the client closes the connection early?

```
class AccessLogFilter extends Filter with Results {
  override def apply(next: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(request: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    result.onFailure {
        case t: Throwable => // log access, error
    }
    result.map { value =>
      var responseLength = 0L
      val insturmentedBody = value.body.map { chunk =>
        responseLength += chunk.length
        chunk
      }.onDoneEnumerating {
        // log access with response length
      }
      Result(value.header, insturmentedBody, value.connection)
    }
  }
}
```